# C - IF(char[] == "ZYX") don't work

Tags: c, arduino

I send from arduino to arduino string (I2C), catch and save to char[10]. When I compare this variable to text, condition don't have execute :-/ And I don't know why...

```
char dataRx[10] = "";

void DaemonReceiving(int howMany){
  int index = 0;

  while(Wire.available() > 0){
    char c = Wire.read();

    dataRx[index++] = c;
    dataRx[index] = '\0';
  }
  Serial.println(dataRx);

  if(dataRx == "HELLO"){
        Wire.beginTransmission(1);
        Wire.write("HI");
        Wire.endTransmission();
  }
}
```

Comment: Learn about `strcmp()`

Comment: Remember that `"HELLO"`, at runtime, will be a character pointer (a `char const *`). `dataRx` is a pointer that points somewhere else, so the equality expression will never be true since the question it's asking is "do these two pointers point to the same location."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compare the dataRX string to "HELLO", use:

```
if (strcmp (dataRx,"HELLO") == 0) {

    // matches HELLO

}
```

Comment: What was the output of Serial.println(dataRx)?

Comment: HELLO
When I write:
    case 0:
    Serial.println("0");
      if(strcmp(dataRx,"HELLO") == 0){

uC don't write "0" and condition too ;) But, when I change strcmp(dataRx,"HELLO") == 0 on strcmp(dataRx,"HELLO") == 1, uC print on console this 0...

Answer (score 4):

If it's C you have to use `strcmp`, otherwise you're just comparing two pointers -the location of "HELLO" and the location of dataRx (which will fail)

Note that this doesn't have anything to do with arduino :)

Comment: When I write this, my function DaemonReceiving don't work... I think arduino freezes.

Comment: Note that this doesn't have anything to do with arduino :) -> Have. I make this on arduino ;)

Comment: Add some debug code, print to the console window (or a display) and see where exactly it fails

Comment: I add Serial.println("1/2/3/4/5...") on setup() (I see this), before and after condition and nothing (I cant see).

Comment: Ok, I know, but this is abnormal :)
Your condition is good and executed, but uC freezes on next lines:

    Wire.beginTransmission(1);
    Wire.write("HI");
    Wire.endTransmission();

Answer (score 4):

This compares pointer values:

```
if(dataRx == "HELLO")
```

you need [strcmp](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcmp/) string comparison:

```
if(strcmp(dataRx, "HELLO") == 0)
```