# how to compare array of chars with arduino

Tags: arduino

i want to compare the text that i receive from gsm board in arduino with the word Misure and Reset and reply in different case depending on request but the arduino jump on ams.flush() without reply nothing. please help me thanks

```
//Message REceiving
void receivemsg(float temperature){
 char c;
    char d[200];
    int i;


  {
    Serial.println("Message received from:");

    // Get remote number
    sms.remoteNumber(senderNumber, 20);
    Serial.println(senderNumber);

    // An example of message disposal    
    // Any messages starting with # should be discarded
    if(sms.peek()=='#')
    {
      Serial.println("Discarded SMS");
      sms.flush();
    }

    // Read message bytes and print them
    while(c=sms.read()){
       d[i]=c;
      Serial.print(c);
//      for (i=0;i<200;i++){
//      d[i]=c;}
}
          Serial.println("\nEND OF MESSAGE");


      // interpreter of the message
      for (i=0;i<200;i++){
      if (d[i]=='Misure')
      // part of reply message 
      {


 String t="Hello i'm Arduino: Umidità del terreno attuale (0-50): "+ String(sensorValue);
 String f= " Temeratura attuale: ";
 String d= ftoa(temperature,2,6);

String txt=t+f+d;
 char txtMsg[200];
 txt.toCharArray(txtMsg,140);
  sms.beginSMS(senderNumber);
  sms.print(txtMsg);
  sms.endSMS(); 
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");}}

      for (i=0;i<200;i++){      
if (d[i]=='Reset'){
    char txtMsg[200]={"Reset Received... i'm resetting now please be patient thanks"};
    sms.beginSMS(senderNumber);
    sms.print(txtMsg);
    sms.endSMS();
    Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");
     //calling watchdog
      Reset_AVR();}}


    // Delete message from modem memory to prevent full  memory space error
    sms.flush();
    Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
  delay(1000);
  return;
}}
```

Comment: You seem to have two different variables called `d`. You also need to format your code properly - it's pretty much unreadable at present.

Comment: Your code is broken both literally, and probably algorithmically as well.  If you want to compare array elements to a constant string treated as an array, you must compare to its elements, for example `if (d[i]=="Misure"[i])`.  However this may well not work for you, as it is unclear that you can assume the received characters will start with the desired string.  You may instead need something which checks each incoming character against `"Misure"[0]`, if it matches increments a state variable so checks the next character against `"Misure"[1]` and so on until it has found the full string.

Comment: Misure is a constant set of char that i want to check if it is equal to the sms that i receive... not an array

Comment: You probably wanted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580332/1057527)

Answer (score 0):

Declare new array with your word
`char name[6]={'M','i','s','u','r','e'}`
then

```
int x=0
for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
 if(name[i]=d[i]){
   int x=1;         
 }else{
   x=0;
   break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subString() function

substring() with only one parameter looks for a given substring from the position given to the end of the string. It expects that the substring extends all the way to the end of the String. For example:

```
String stringOne = "Content-Type: text/html";



// substring(index) looks for the substring from the index position to //the end:
  if (stringOne.substring(19) == "html") {
   }
```

is true, while

```
String stringOne = "Content-Type: text/html";
    // substring(index) looks for the substring from the index position to the end:
  if (stringOne.substring(19) == "htm") {
   }
```

is not true, because there's an l after the htm in the String.